# VBA: Combining ranges and joining to string

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to combine two ranges and then join the full list of terms as a comma delimited list.

Both ranges are lists of terms: i.e. ManualTags is `A1:A5` which is `tag1, tag2, tag3`, and so on. Dynamic tags is the the same kind of list, but just different words, which is located at `B1:B10`.

So I'd call it like this: `SEARCHFORTAGS(A1:A5, B1:B10)`

This works:

```
Function SEARCHFORTAGS(ManualTags As Range, DynamicTags As Range)
    SEARCHFORTAGS = Join(Application.Transpose(ManualTags.Value), ", ")
End Function
```

And returns: `"tag1, tag2, tag3, etc"`

But when I try to combine the two types of tags first and then combine that, it fails.

```
Function SEARCHFORTAGS(ManualTags As Range, DynamicTags As Range)
    joinedTags = Union(ManualTags, DynamicTags)
    SEARCHFORTAGS = Join(Application.Transpose(joinedTags.Value), ", ")
End Function
```

which returns `#VALUE!`

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `Transpose` "converts a vertical range of cells to a horizontal range, or vice versa".  Once you perform a `Union` of a 5 rows x 1 column range with a 10 rows x 1 column range, you don't have a "vertical" range **or** a "horizontal" range - so it isn't going to like you.

Answer (score 1):

The Transpose method fails with error 1004 "Unable to get the Transpose property of the WorksheetFunction class" when passed a multiple-area Range.

The multiple-area range is produced by the Union method. The following code, added below your line `joinedTags = Union(ManualTags, DynamicTags)`, will iterate over the Areas collection and display each item's address in the Debug Window:

```
Dim unionArea As Excel.Range
For Each unionArea In joinedTags.Areas
    Debug.Print unionArea.Address
Next
```

In your case, this function would work, as long as each range passed as an argument is single-area and has only one column:

```
Function SEARCHFORTAGS(ManualTags As Range, DynamicTags As Range)
    SEARCHFORTAGS = Join(Application.Transpose(ManualTags.Value), ", ") & ", " & Join(Application.Transpose(DynamicTags.Value), ", ")
End Function
```